# Original spelling of Polish surname is missing

Tags: immigration, surnames, poland, canada, 1900s-decade

My grandfather immigrated to Canada from Poland in 1909 with his parents.  Our original surname's spelling was changed upon arrival in Canada.  Since then it has been "Kerunsky" and no one kept record.  But without the original spelling, I cannot trace our family roots back to Poland.

Any ideas on how to find out?

Comment: If you include the names and ages of that immigrant family, port of arrival (if known) and ship name (if known) it may help potential answerers to help you.

Comment: You say "Our original surname's spelling was changed upon arrival in Canada."  Are you basing this on a passenger arrival list? Those immigration lists were created in the departure ports, not the arrival ports. If you have an arrival list, does it say who bought the tickets? (It might not have been the passenger.)   Your question could be improved by adding a list of documents you've already found for the family -- that allows us to point out clues you may have missed.